# Eclipse - How to know the 'real' Java version of web application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working on a sort-of-old web application. During a discussion with my boss, I mentioned that the application is using `Java 1.4`. Then, he interrupted me, then said that the project is actually using `Java 1.5`. I opened my workspace and show the reason why I said that the project is using Java 1.4. I navigated to `Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries`, listed here is **JRE System Library[J2SE-1.4]**.

He then took the control then brought me to `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler` then in the **JDK Compliance section, Compiler compliance level has the value 1.5**.

Another thing that made me think that the project is using 1.4 is because, the `List` objects does not have parameterized type, and no warning is generated by Eclipse for them. 
Also, when I type `List<String>`, eclipse gives me an error saying

**Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5**.

This made me convinced that the application is using Java 1.5. But in my current position (junior developer) I need to make sure that my assumption is really correct before entering a debate with my boss. So, my question is, how do I really know the Java version that the application is using? What is difference between the Java version stated in

`Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries`

and

`Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your boss showed you, was the installed JDK/JRE, which is 1.5, but these are backwards compatible, so you can make a 1.5 JDK to produce 1.4 compatible code. That is what you saw on the project properties (which is the proper place to see)

So,

`Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler` : Installed JDK's and workspace-level compiler settings. In your case, a 1.5 JDK installed, configured to compile 1.5 code

`Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries` : Project specific settings, that override the workspace settings. In your case, use the J2SE 1.4 compatibility of the 1.5 JDK, to produce 1.4 code.

You can also see the project facets (Java), it should say 1.4  ;

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes, `Project Facet` is also 1.4. So, how can I make the JDK 1.5 to produce Java 1.5 code for the project? Also, will switching affect anything (syntax/logic) in the application?

Comment: On Project properties, you can check at Java Compiler section... and disable the "Enable Project Specific Settings". Also you can edit the Project Facet to 1.5... And lastly, you can edit the J2SE 1.4 entry on Java Build Path, to a J2SE 1.5 entry.. or directly specify the 1.5 JDK to use

Answer (score 2):

`Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler`: Specifies the default compilation levels to be used by the projects in the current workspace. it also uses the default JRE specified in `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`

`Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries`: Specifies the JRE used by the selected project, by default it will be the default JRE specified for the workspace but it can be changed. The compilation levels used by the project can be found at the location `Project Properties > Java Compiler`, this also by default gets copied from the workspace but can be modified for individual projects

In your case since `Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries` has java 1.4, it is using java 1.4 and to make sure the compiler compliance level you can visit `Project Properties > Java Compiler`